# Access two web servers (VPS and Windows Server) through the same IP (PUBLIC AND VPN) using VPN

Tags: iptables, vpn, vps, openvpn

I have two servers: a hosted VPS with a website on port 80, and a home server running windows 7.  See the diagram below.

The home server is running WAMP on port 88, which works on my home's public and local IPs. When connecting both servers together (the home server and hosted VPS) using OPENVPN this port becomes blocked and the website is not accessible at VPN(IP):88.

I have had success before, I ran a **single website on a home server** behind a **hosted VPN** and opened port 80 with iptables so the IP becomes static using the VPN address. VPN(IP):80 would then work, allowing me to access the home server on port 80 using the VPN IP.

Is it possible to have two websites running using the VPN IP on different ports from different servers? Port 80 with the VPS PUBLIC IP would point to the VPS LAMP server and Port 88 with the VPN IP would point to the WAMP home server.

[image: network diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not relevant to serverfault, the short version is yes.

To pass port 88 back to your home server, you will need three rules at least:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 88 -j DNAT --to <internal VPN address>
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun+ -p tcp --dport 88 -j ACCEPT
```

You may also want:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i tun+ -o <external IF> -j SNAT --to <VPS IP>
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

You will also want to verify your ip_forward sysctl is enabled.

Comment: Worked perfect, only thing I needed to do was add rules for incoming traffic on the home server. Appreciated!